# Cron job to delete files created before a specific time

Tags: php, linux, cron, cpanel

I have this cron job to empty a temp folder I have once a day:

```
rm -rf /home/username/public_html/temp/*
```

I want this cron job to delete all files which created before the it will run with 5 minutes and up just to make sure that my script don't need these files anymore.

Let's say I set the cron job to run everyday at 10:00 AM .. I want it to delete all files in this folder which created before 09:55 AM

Thank you so much experts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GNU `find`, try this:

```
find /home/username/public_html/temp -type f -mmin +5 -delete
```

Should also work with FreeBSD or many other versions of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution would be:-

point cron job to execute a php file once a day.

```
 $dir = 'your/directory/';
  foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v){
  $last_modified = filemtime($v);//get the last modified time of file
  $fmtime=date("h:i:s", $last_modified);
  $currentTime=date("h:i:s");

  if (//check here if your file is created before 09:55Am)
  unlink($v);

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Glob `*.*`?? I think your DOS is showing.  That will only match files with a dot in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jeffreys answer, I'd suggest something like this:

```
for i in `find /home/username/public_html/temp -type f -mmin +5`
    do rm $i
done
```